# Grails GSP: <g:widget ... /> throws no such property on nested Numbers

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I'm currently developing a grails application (Version 3.1.2) and I got a frustrating error that I currently cannot solve.

Lets have an example case:

```
// Domain classes
class RootBean {
    NestedBean nestedBean
}

class NestedBean {
    int nestedInteger
}
```

not much to say about it, its just an 1 to 1 relation with no back reference

Now lets specify my problem: I've got a create and an edit view which both render a editTemplate with all the possible inputs. With a new Object (create) everythings works fine but with a existing Object I want to update I get this GSP Error Message:

```
URI
   /VMPMessung/edit/2
Class
   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
Message
   Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: [views/rootBean/edit.gsp:13] Error executing tag <g:render>: [views/rootBean/_editTemplate.gsp:1] Error executing tag <g:form>: [views/rootBean/_editTemplate.gsp:150] Error executing tag <f:widget>: No such property: nestedInteger for class: RootBean
Caused by
   No such property: nestedInteger for class: RootBean
```

The GSP Code:

```
<f:widget class="form-control"
       property="nestedBean.nestedInteger"
       bean="RootBean"/>
```

I also debugged through the Taglibary and discoverd that it's going wrong cause of the Type Integer, I got other String fields in the real object and they are working fine. The Error is thrown in the `FormFieldsTagLib` class at line `569`

```
private CharSequence renderNumericInput(BeanPropertyAccessor propertyAccessor,Map model, Map attrs) {
    if (!attrs.type && model.constraints?.inList) {
         attrs.from = model.constraints.inList
    if (!model.required) attrs.noSelection = ["": ""]
        return g.select(attrs)
    } else if (model.constraints?.range) {
        attrs.type = attrs.type ?: "range"
        attrs.min = model.constraints.range.from
        attrs.max = model.constraints.range.to
    } else {
        attrs.type = attrs.type ?: getDefaultNumberType(model )
        if (model.constraints?.scale != null) attrs.step = "0.${'0' * (model.constraints.scale - 1)}1"
        if (model.constraints?.min != null) attrs.min = model.constraints.min
        if (model.constraints?.max != null) attrs.max = model.constraints.max
    }

    if(propertyAccessor != null && attrs.value) {
        attrs.value = g.fieldValue(bean: propertyAccessor.rootBean, field: propertyAccessor.propertyName)
        // This call causes the Error
        // Debugging Values: propertyAccessor.rootBean: RootBean, 
        // propertyAccessor.propertyName: nestedInteger
    }
    return g.field(attrs)
}
```

I guess they are trying to find the fieldName on the RootBean instead of the NestedBean but am I doing something wrong or is it a Bug on Grails side?

Hopefully some of you knows an answer to this, its really much a blocker for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same issue, the weird thing is that in  I am not having problem, I have it only in

I could fix it with a workaround, implementing in RootBean class a getter for nestedInteger:

```
def int getNumber() {
    return nestedBean?.nestedInteger
}
```

That worked for me.
Could you solve it properly?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the hint, ill give it a try tomorrow morning. I will let you know

Comment: Well, that actually worked for me, too. Didn't find a other solution yet :/ I guess it is not worth the effort

Comment: I am glad that it worked for you @dennis-bukowski ! I guess the same, perhaps we should open an issue with that. In my opinion if this is an issue it has to be fixed in future versions of Grails.